# what are the list of linux terminal commands that can be used in Git bash?

Tags: linux, git

I am a new user to git and linux.What are the list of linux terminal commands that can be used in the git bash?

Answer (score 0):

The list of linux commands supported should be in the `/bin` directory. In a Git Bash terminal if you do a `ls -l /bin`, then that should give you an idea of what is supported.

Other than that, if you asked this question because there was a command missing, I would suggest using Cygwin and installing git in it.

Comment: More correctly, the list of commands "automatically" available includes any executables in the directories in your `$PATH`. Plus any other commands reachable by giving an explicit path. If you start typing something, then hit tab twice, that will usually give you a list of commands from your `$PATH` that are available to complete your command.

Answer (score 0):

`git help -a` for all commands.

`git help -g` for guides.